# Can not unmount a device using "umount" in Docker

Tags: build, docker

I don't know why but, umount is not working in docker.

```
umount: loop3/: must be superuser to umount
```

Let me share one more thing that is 
It creates `loop3` under `/mnt/loop3` in real machine. Which is most unexpected thing for me, because promises pure virtual environment.

Why? Any solution?

#### Scenario :

I created docker `ubuntu:13.04` to create cross compilation environment.

- Docker Linux machine (ubuntu):

  ```
  Linux 626089eadfeb 3.10.45-1-lts #1 SMP Fri Jun 27 06:44:23 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- Linux Machine (rch Linux):

  ```
  Linux localhost 3.10.45-1-lts #1 SMP Fri Jun 27 06:44:23 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

#### Docker Info

```
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.3
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.3
Git commit (server): 990021a
```

Comment: Looks like you already got an answer on the [github issue you reported](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/6879#issuecomment-48215492). Following the suggestion there helped me.

Comment: Ya @DharmitShah but it's haven't solved yet. Actually second level cross compilation is not working perfectly. Creating problems in `mounting` in device n all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution :

In default docker run it's not a real Operating system as we expect. It doesn't have permissions to access the devices. So we have to use **`--privileged`** While running a docker.

By default, Docker containers are `"unprivileged"` and cannot, for example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container. This is because by default a container is not allowed to access any devices, but a `"privileged"` container is given access to all devices.

When the operator executes **`docker run --privileged`**, Docker will enable to access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in AppArmor to allow the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside containers on the host.

Comment: Is there any other more secure way to do this? Giving --priviliged gives the full host system access to docker. And as /proc/sys/fs is inside docker should it not allow to do it without --priviliged?

Comment: What if your container is already running?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't follow the accepted answer `--privileged` give too much permission consider using `--cap-add=CAP_SYS_ADMIN` that guard many many function but less than privileged:

> Perform a range of system administration operations
> including: quotactl(2), mount(2), umount(2),

Here we want the mount(2)/umount(2).

If you want to be safe you can cap-add and in the entrypoint drop this capability with prtcl (it depend on the language you use for C/python it is quite easy, maybe prctl has binding for your language).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the [mount](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount) command  of linux but it is also valid for `unmount`.

The previous solution is valid but my scenario could not execute the command '`docker run`' since it was being used in real time.

The command I wanted to mount :

```
mount -o remount,size=5G /dev/shm
```

## Solution

Verification in the docker :

```
[docker]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm              64M  4.0K   64M   1% /dev/shm
[docker]$ exit
```

We look for the ID of our container :

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE   
<container_id>      nameimage
```

*Let's memorize that beginning of the ID*

All the following commands must be executed with  `sudo` (*use in the shortest possible time*) :

```
# sudo -i
```

We go to the folder that contains the docker :

```
# By default
cd /var/lib/docker/containers/
```

And we open the folder that begins on .

```
cd <container_id>
```

We execute our command with the necessary parameters :

```
mount -o remount,size=5G shm
```

(*Note: I do not remember if the command must be executed to show the file system*)

Finally we enter the Docker and verify that the values ​​have been updated correctly:

```
[docker]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm             5.0G     0  5.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

### Sources

- https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1278

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem during starting docker service.

A cause was not having enough space left on the hard drive.
After **cleaning up the disk and rebooting** - docker service started successfully.